# jQuery draggable / sortable on dynamically-created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

After some blood, sweat and luckily no tears I've managed to create a drag and drop system which fits my needs.

There are only 2 things that are almost triggering my tears...

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pym3m3bm/4/)

The problem is in these lines of code, but can't find it:

```
if (dropped === original) {

    $("#dropzone").append('<li class="placeholder" data-id="" data-order="" data-content=""></li>');

    init();

}

$(".remove").click(function() {

    var removable = $(this).parent();

    if (dropped > original) {

        removable.remove();
        removable.removeClass("dropped");
        removable.removeClass("ui-droppable-disabled");

    } else {

        removable.empty();
        removable.removeClass("dropped");
        removable.removeClass("ui-droppable-disabled");

    }

    init();

});
```

So now the explanation and my goal:

There are 5 days and on default the placeholders will dynamicly increase with the number of days. If the max limit of placeholders is filled, another one will be appended. Now, after the not-default placeholder is appended and I delete a previous filled placeholder, I can't allow it to be droppable again.

Difficult to explain, but see the demo above ^

**Extra**: I would like to be able to drag items between those placeholders. But can't find a way either.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You should attach your blood and sweat too, otherwise we can't find the source of the problem...

Comment: The blood and sweat is pushed into a jsfiddle :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to reactivate the `droppable` on delete. And also, `destroy` them on `drop` might make you need to recreate them. You could use `disable` on drop and `enable` when deleting. Like this:

```
drop: function (event, ui) {
   var dragging = ui.draggable.clone().find("img").remove();
   $(this).append(dragging).addClass("dropped");
    $(this).droppable('disable');
```

And later:

```
if (dropped > original) {
     $(this).parent().droppable('enable')
    removable.remove();
    removable.removeClass("dropped");
    removable.removeClass("ui-droppable-disabled");
       } else {
    $(this).parent().droppable('enable');               
    removable.empty();
    removable.removeClass("dropped");
    removable.removeClass("ui-droppable-disabled");
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/opmd46t2/3/

Comment: Thanks, that works for me. The explanation makes sense.. Thanks alot, any suggestions on how to make the draggable items create a space between the placeholders and append it there? I've been searching alot, but can't seem to find a way.

Comment: you mean when you drag them into your dropzone? Like a sortable?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That would be the "extra" thing :)

Comment: You already have sortable behavior, it's just that your dropzone has 0 height so it's not triggered. And connectWithSortable should point to #dropzone. But you'd have to modify a lot your behaviors to make it work.